# jekyll: Is it possible to use a page.variable, as an operator inside a conditional if statement?

Tags: json, jekyll, liquid

JSON file in path: `_data/integers.json` which looks like this:

```
{
    "100": [
        {
            "value": "true"
        }
    ]
}
```

In Jekyll page:

```
---

integers:
- 100
- 200

---
```

What I'm trying to do:

```
{% assign json = site.data.integers %}
{% for integer in page.integers %} // loop
 {% if json.{{ integer }}[0].value == "true" %} ... {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

e.g. use the `{{ integer }}` (aka `page.integer[0]`) as an operator inside the conditional statement.

Is there a method? ... asking for a friend.

Answer (score 1):

If we keep your json and page.integers as is :

```
{% assign json = site.data.integers %}
{{ json | inspect }}
{% for integer in page.integers %}
  {% comment %} Here we cast our integer to a string, 
                as json keys are strings
                (100 | append:"" => "100")
  {% endcomment %}
  {% assign intAsStr = integer | append:"" %}

  {% comment %} as a possible json[intAsStr] returns an array,
                we retrieve the first and only element in it 
  {% endcomment %}
  {% assign data = json[intAsStr].first %}

  {% if data["value"] == "true" %}
    <h1>We have a match on {{ intAsStr }}</h1>
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

We can simplify a little with some refactoring

**data/integers.json**

```
{
    "100": { "value": true }
}
```

**jekyll page**

```
---
integers:
  - "100"
  - "200"
---

{% assign json = site.data.integers %}
{{ json | inspect }}
{% for integer in page.integers %}
  {% assign data = json[integer] %}
  {% if data["value"] == true %}
     <h1>We have a match on {{ integer }}</h1>
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```